# Do TypeScript definition files have to be at the root of a package?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Supposed I have a TypeScript package that contains two files, which are (for whatever reason) at least technically not related to each other, but independent. In addition, there is no `index.ts` file or something like that which acts as a unified entry point, instead the files from this package are meant to be imported individually.

So, we have a folder structure like this:

```
src/
  a.ts
  b.ts
dist/
  a.js
  a.d.ts
  b.js
  b.d.ts
package.json
```

For obvious reasons I can not put a single `.d.ts` file into the `types` field of the `package.json`. Now if I import a file like this:

```
import a from 'somepackage/a';
```

Do IDEs detect the correct `.d.ts` file, or do I need to do anything in a different way? Is this the official way to go, or is there anything else I need to watch out for, or that I have to do to make things work?

Comment: Related https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8305

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bundle the typings with your package, you should [reference your type definitions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) within your package.json-file using the "types" property:

```
{
  "name": "whatever-package",
  ...
  "main": "./dist/main.js"
  "types": "./dist/typings.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately "types" supports only one string value, so you may only pass one path which should contain the bundled type definitions. This is because it's meant as counterpart to your main entry file (where only 1 path is supported as well).

edit: To work around this restriction your typings file (as well as your main entry file) may simply be a wrapper exporting the concrete definitions like this:

typings.d.ts

```
export { SomeObject } from './path/SomeObject';
export { SomeOtherObject } from './some/other/path/SomeOtherObject';
```

In this case SomeObject.d.ts and SomeOtherObject.d.ts should exist on the corresponding paths.